# How to automate OWASP ZAP Fuzzing

Tags: zap

Is there any way I can automate fuzzing in zap. I know how to do it manually. But is there any way to create test suite and execute?

Answer (score 2):

Using Zap? No, other than setting up the word lists and launching it (which is what I assume you mean by doing it manually). Using python or another scripting language? Yes, absolutely, and this is very common with pen-testers who do it often.

Comment: Got you point. You mean to say 1) ZAP does not provide any automated testing functionality? 2) For this we need to use third party tool like selenium?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You might also consider a paid version of Burp, which is much more powerful (but it does cost $$!)

Comment: @MuhammadAliKhamis if this answered your question, please mark it as "answered"